# Adding supported libraries in android application

Tags: android, libraries

I'm a newbee in android platform. Im trying to create one appliccation in the latest version. but i want to run that app in the lowest versions.I just heared about using supported libraries along with the application.
I have some doubts about that

1. How we can add supported libraries in our application, from where we can download that?
2. when we develop using spported libraries .when we run on a lowest platform , which functionalities of the highest version we can use?
3. is highest versions UI is supported in lowest version?
4. give some example for adding the supported libraries..

Thanx in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Support Library is a quiet extending topic. I would suggest to read through it [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html). But here are some answeres to your questions.

1. Just Right Click on your project > Android Tools > Add Support
   Library (With the little Android icon.)
2. What exactly is supported can be read here [Using the v4 Library
   APIs](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Using). It adds support for some of the most useful features of
   later Android versions. Take a look at Fragments, Loaders and
   ViewPagers.
3. If I understand your question correctly, there are some view you can
   use with the support library, but if you want the Actionbar in 2.3
   you need to use a library like ActionBarSherlock.
4. An example for adding the support library is a little hard, just do
   what I wrote in 1. But here is a example of using the support
   library with Fragments.

First import the support library classes:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

And then us them:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.content);

    // getSupportFragmentManager() is for getting the 
    // FragmentManager of the Support Library
    // this is the only support library part
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

    // from here like a normal fragment, create the fragment
    Fragment frag = ExampleFragment.instantiate(this, "ExampleFragmentName");

    //  start a fragment transaction
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    // add the fragment to the transaction
    ft.add(R.id.content, frag);

    // commit the fragment transaction
    ft.commit();
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 4):

1. See link from @Marko Niciforovic
2. Support library is as said mostly for the support of fragment and fragment transaction before Android 3.0
3. Simple and short answer is no. You would have to write your own Themes and Styles.
4. Eclipse --> Right click on project --> Android Tools --> Add support library

If it's not working, check that on the projects build path --> right click project --> build path --> configure build path in the tab order & export the "Android Private Libraries" or "*android-support-vx.jar" is exported (checkbox ticked).

Hope we could answer your questions.

Answer (score 1):

I think supported lib is mostly used for fragments because they are added in 3.0. To use android support library you can download it directly from eclipse, check here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/support-lib.html, but mostly its something like this:

Eclipse -> Window -> Android SDK and AVD Manager -> Available Packages -> Android Support

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html

Downloading the Support Package
The Support Package is provided as a downloadable package from the Android SDK Manager. To install:

Launch the Android SDK Manager.

1. From Eclipse, you can select Window > Android SDK Manager. Or, launch SDK Manager.exe from the / directory (on Windows only) or android from the /tools/ directory.
   Expand the Android Repository, check Android Support package and click Install selected.
   Proceed to install the package.
2. When done, all files (including source code, samples, and the .jar files) are saved into the /extras/android/support/ directory. This directory contains each of the different support libraries, such as the library for API level 4 and up and the library for API level 13 and up, each named with the respective version (such as v4/).
   Open Android SDK MAnager. Scroll down to Extras. Under Extras choose Android Support library and click install.

[image]

Setting Up a Project to Use a Library

1. In your Android project, create a directory named libs at the root of your project (next to src/, res/, etc.)
2. Locate the JAR file for the library you want to use and copy it into the libs/ directory.
   For example, the library that supports API level 4 and up is located at /extras/android/support/v4/android-support-v4.jar.
3. Add the JAR to your project build path.
   In Eclipse, right-click the JAR file in the Package Explorer, select Build Path > Add to Build Path.

Check the link below under the topic **Using the v4 Library APIs**

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html#Downloading

Answer (score 1):

Don't start with the latest SDK all the time. Start with the minimum version may be ginger bread 2.3. Use ICS only if u want to add ICS specific items such as expandable widgets and all.